# Bug on Standard Record Detail component on Lightning: duplicated information on sections

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have been using Standard Record Detail info adding it into Lightning App Builder to display fields of an custom object that I have created.

On Page layout, I have created a couple of sections to separate this fields information:

[image]

And it is showed like this on Lightning Experience:

[image]

I can edit, save and everything is working as expected, but if I collapse/expand a section and edit it again, I see duplicated information as here:

[image]

I have tried on a Trailhead org and a Developer Org and it is happening in both. Is this a known issue? Thanks.

Comment: Also found here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MUTMQA4